# Page flickers when new html5 video loads

Tags: css, html

I am making a website using WordPress. I have included an HTML code to play 3 videos in a loop at the top of the page. Initially, all the video plays in sequence without any issue. But during the second iteration, every time a video finishes playing and the next one loads, the content below the video flickers. Not the whole page, but only top portion of the content. Seems like the content gets displaced for a fraction of a second. It may be a height issue.

HTML:

```
<div>
    <div class="splash">
      <div class="playreel-padding">
        <div class="playreel"><a class="vp-a" href="https://vimeo.com/181701051"><img src="wp-content/uploads/reel/playreel.png" /></a></div>
      </div>
    <div id="splash-img" class="splash-img"><img id="splash-imgchild" src="wp-content/uploads/reel/airbnb_website.jpg" /></div>
      <video id="splash-video" class="video-playing" preload="auto" muted> 
      </video>
    </div>
    <div class="container-banner-group2">
      <div class="decocenter2"><img src="wp-content/uploads/2018/05/Ribbon.png" /></div>
    </div>
  <div id="vidgallery">

    [smart-grid row_height="250" fixed_height="true" margins="0" font_type="google" google_font="Fredericka the Great"]

    [gallery ids="3499,3479,3504,3514,3486,3481,3494,3485,3487,3490,3488,3507,3506,3482,3498,3492,3500,3503,3491,3496,3497" orderby="rand"]

    [/smart-grid]

  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container-banner-group2{
    float: left;
    /*height: 615px;*/
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 950;
    pointer-events: none;

}

.decocenter2{
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 690px;
    vertical-align :top;
    -ms-transform: translate(0px,-80px); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: translate(0px,-80px); /* Safari */
    transform: translate(0px,-80px);
    margin:0 auto;  
    position: relative;
}
.decocenter2 img{
    width: 100%;
}
.video-padding-img{
    width: 100%;
    visibility: none;
}

.video-padding {
    z-index: -10;
    visibility: none;
}

.playreel-padding{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;

    height: 100%;

}

.playreel{
    position: relative;
    width: 234px;
    margin:0 auto;
    z-index: 2000;
    top: 200px;

}
.splash img{
    width: 100%;
}
.splash-img{
    position: absolute;
    width:100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}
#splash-imgchild{
    position: absolute;
    width:100%;
    z-index: 1;
    object-fit: cover;
}
.video-playing{
    position: relative;
    width:100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    z-index:2;
}
.video-mask{
    background-image: url("wp-content/uploads/reel/mask.png");
    z-index: 5;
    position: relative;
    object-fit: cover;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
    .decocenter2{
    transform: translate(0px,-40px);
    }
}
@media (max-width: 1440px) {
    .playreel{
    top: 100px;
        
    }

}
@media (max-width: 1100px) {
    .playreel{
        top: 40px;  
    }

}
@media (max-width: 800px) {
    .playreel{
        top: 40px;
        width: 134px;   
    }

}
@media (max-width: 500px) {
    .playreel{
        top: 15px;
        width: 134px;   
    }

    #splash-video{
           visibility: hidden;
       
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Does this all videos have the same height and width? I have just added a height for the video tag and the flickering issue is solved. You can either use a static height or use jquery to add height dynamically at page load.

Comment: Wow. That was surprisingly easy. Please add it as an answer and I will upvote it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this all videos have the same height and width? I have just added a height for the video tag and the flickering issue is solved. You can either use a static height or use jquery to add height dynamically at page load.

Comment: Adipopli.. you can upvote also..

Comment: Not with my current reputation.